# how to output my functions numeric values as a list in python

Tags: python, function

here is my function:

```
def seq_sum(n):
    """ input: n, generate a sequence of n random coin flips
        output: return the number of heads 
        Hint: For simplicity, use 1,0 to represent head,tails
    """
    flip = 0
    heads = 0
    while flip <= n:
        coin = random.randint(0,2)
        flip += 1
        if coin == 1:
            heads += 1

    print(heads)
```

the output looks like this:

```
55
1
0
2
1
```

and so on. but what I want is the number of heads, plus a LIST of the output:

```
55

[1, 0, 2, 1, .....]
```

when I tried print(list(heads))I get the following error message:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That's not the output of a single function call, but multiple ones I guess? Nowhere do you return anything in the function, only printing.

Comment: If you random 0 and 1's, why not let them represent heads, tails using sum?

Comment: Create list for results and append coin at every loop spin. Then return results from function.

Comment: what's the meaning of having the random range include `2`? when heads are `1` and tails are `0`... is it a three sided coin?

Comment: `random.randint` returns a random integer in range [a, b], _including both end points_.  So you need to use `random.randint(0, 1)`.

Comment: The class is written in Python 2, not Python 3. In Python 3, both ends are inclusive. It doesn't run when I put it through on Python 2 unless I use the range [0,2] so I am assuming the end is NOT inclusive in Python 2

Comment: @HeatherMoseley Your assumption is not correct.  Same behavior in both versions.  Here is the link for Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: @Alexander Hmmm. Yes, I see. Well then, next question I guess would be why the function, random.randit(0,1) returns all zeros? Everything runs fine when I put it through my Anaconda platform. I only run into issues when I run it through the homework notebook. Possibly this has something to do with the teacher's call to function or assertion statements: 

x = seq_sum(100)
print x
assert unique([seq_sum(2) for x in  range(0,200)]).tolist() == [0, 1, 2]

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you are merely keeping track of the total number of heads and not their history.  You need to create an iterable collection to hold the interim values, such as a list or Numpy Array.

```
import numpy as np

def seq_sum(n):
    flips = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=n)
    return sum(flips), flips.tolist()

# Example usage.
total_heads, flips = seq_sum(n=10)
```

Note that the start and end points are inclusive and exclusive, respectively, for numpy's `randint` function.

Comment: The homework specifically requires that I use random.rand in the function and that I cannot import any libraries. The call to the function is already written by the teachers :(

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will do what you want

```
def seq_sum(n):
    flips = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n)]
    return sum(flips), flips
```

Usage

```
s, l = seq_sum(10)
```

From the comment in your code I can tell that the function should return only the number of heads so

```
def seq_sum(n):
    return sum(random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n))
```

Comment: I thought of this, but because the random range includes (0, 1 or **2**), then the result will be wrong as you're assuming there are only heads (that's why you summed the list). I think there a bit of mistake in the question itself.

Comment: I think the range includes (0 or 1) to be sure you can look at the comment in the code

Comment: that's true it's there in the comment, but the range is `random.randint(0, 2)` and the both outputs in the question contain 2 which's weird..

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

# edit in place
def seq_sum(n):
    """ input: n, generate a sequence of n random coin flips
        output: return the number of heads 
        Hint: For simplicity, use 1,0 to represent head,tails
    """
    flip = 0
    heads = 0
    seq = list()
    while flip <= n:
        coin = random.randint(0,2)
        seq.append(coin)
        flip += 1
        if coin == 1:
            heads += 1

    print(heads,seq)


#solution 2
def seq_sum(n):
    flip = 0
    seq = list() #create a list to store every random value
    while flip < n: # if want to generate n values, the while loop only need compare 0,1,2,...n-1 times, so you need <, not <=.
        coin = random.randint(0,1)  # coin has only two sides
        seq.append(coin)
        flip += 1
    return seq
    # print(heads) # it is not good idea to print data in function.
random_list = seq_sum(55)
head_num = sum(random_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but here's my quite simple solution.

```
import random

def seq_sum(n):
""" input: n, generate a sequence of n random coin flips
    output: return the number of heads 
    Hint: For simplicity, use 1,0 to represent head,tails
"""
  flip = 0
  heads = 0
  outcomes=[]
  while flip < n:
    coin = random.randint(0,2)
    outcomes.append(coin)
    flip += 1
    if coin == 1:
        heads += 1

  print(heads)
  print(outcomes)


--------
```

output in console:

```
>>>seq_sum(3)
>>>2
>>>[1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I tried print(list(heads))I get the following error message:
>
> ```
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Let's start with here. `heads` is always an integer from beginning till the end. Thus, when you put `list( )` around `heads`, Python is complaining that you are feeding `list` an integer, which is not iterable.

**Takeaway 1**: some objects can only take certain kinds of arguments.

**Second stop:** I want to have a list to store the heads and tails. What should I do? One way is to create a list to store it.

```
my_list = [] # or list()
```

To add to the list, you can use `append` method. `append` method adds one element to the end of the list.

```
my_list.append(1)
# now my_list is [1]
my_list.append(0)
# now my_list looks like [1, 0]
```

**Third goal:** I want to randomly generate 0s and 1s to represent tails and heads. Are you really doing what you want to do? Be careful about the functions you call, especially those you are not familiar with. Read about what do the functions do.

> random.randint(a, b)
>       Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. -- documentation for [randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

`randint(0, 2)` will generate 0, 1, 2 randomly, which can represent head, tail, and... ohhh we don't have 3 things to represent.

**Goal 4:** Do you want to return/save the values for later use? or just print it out? Think about it and make the decision. Do you know you can turn 2 things/more at a time?

```
def bar():
    return 1, 2

c = bar()  # c is a tuple that holds two values, 0 and 1 now!
# c[0] == 1 # access the first element with index 0
# c[1] == 2
```

Hope with these, you can code your own answer.